# read a constant on HTML, inside *ngIf

Tags: angular

I am unable to read a constant on HTML, inside `*ngIf`.

```
<span *ngIf="file.name === 'CONSTANTS.fileName' ">
File name same
</span>

export const CONSTANTS{
'fileName':'report'
}
```

I am not able go inside the span as the *ngIf condition is never true though the `CONSTANTS.fileName` exists and i am able to print it on the screen using `{{CONSTANTS.fileName}}`

I also tried "CONSTANTS.fileName". Please guide me where did it went wrong.

Comment: CONSTANTS.fileName is this string or variable?

Comment: How is "CONSTANTS" defined?

Comment: export const CONSTANTS{
'fileName':'report'
}

Answer (score 8):

You are trying to compare a string `'CONSTANTS.fileName'`. Remove single quotes for `CONSTANTS.fileName` so that it is treated as a variable.

```
<span *ngIf="file.name === CONSTANTS.fileName">
File name same
</span>
```

Add another property in the component

`readonly CONSTANTS = CONSTANTS;` to proxy `CONSTANTS`

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/constants-on-template?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Please check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/constants-on-template?file=src/app/app.component.ts It should work. You should also probably add another property in the component `readonly CONSTANTS = CONSTANTS;` to proxy `CONSTANTS`